# Vue 3: How to set ":root"-styles that have been importet with sass variables through the new "@use"-syntax?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I am new to Vue.js and started a new project with Vue 3. Now I don't seem to find any solution for vue regarding this specific following question:

How can variables (i. e. colors) be attached to the ":root" of the page if they have been imported via the new '@use'-syntax from sass in Vue 3?

Here are my example files:

App.vue

```
<style lang="scss">
@use '@/scss/environment/colors' as c;

:root {
  --test-col: #ffffff;
  --test-col2: c.$color-white;
}
</style>
```

_colors.scss

```
$color-white: #FFFFFF;
```

=> Result in Browser Styles:

```
:root {
    --test-col: #000000;
    --test-col2: c.$color-white;
}
```

Apparently, the normal color that I set for "--test-col" with hex code works just fine. But the imported variable for "--test-col2" is not recognized and simply written as the variable-import-syntax used.

Is there a way to make this work with separate file imports or do I have to directly set the colors in the "App.vue"-file?

---

Extra files (for more clarity if necessary):

main.ts

```
import './assets/main.scss'

[some other stuff here ...]
```

main.scss

```
@use '@/scss/base';
```

_base.scss

```
@use 'env' as e;

[some styles here ...]
```

_env.scss

```
@forward 'environment/fonts';
@forward 'environment/properties';
@forward 'environment/colors';
```